# AngularJS 1.x: perform code while in data-ng-repeat...?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code snippet:

```
<select ng-model="option.optionValue">
        <option data-ng-repeat="value in attribute.catalogue.values"
                ng-init="option.optionName = value.name"
                value="{{value.value}}">{{value.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The idea was to assign an `option.optionName` a value of `value.name` when the selection from the option list is made. This (not a surprise) doesn't work as needed, as it just assigns one value when it runs the code and it doesn't change when any selection is made.

Is there a way to overcome this situation? Maybe add this `option.optionName = value.name` code in `data-ng-repeat`?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to override `option.optionName` each time while repeating?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee no, I want to override the value when a selection is made / changed.

Comment: then why you are doing it in `init`? use `ng-options` instead and the ng-model will be automatically update

Comment: ng-model has only one value that is updated, and that is `option.optionValue`, but I also need to update `option.optionName`...

Comment: watch `option.optionValue` and assign in to `option.optionName`

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee can you please give an example, how that could be achieved?

Comment: sure, wait a moment!

Comment: so, whenever there is a selection, you want what value to be strored in `option.optionValue` and what in `option.optionName`?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee thanks your answer solved the problem for me :)

Comment: You are most welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ng-options` to iterate and initialize the options, and update the alternate variable you want to update in selection (though I don't what is the purpose of that when you already have tat value in the `ng-model` variable)

```
<select
    ng-model="option.optionValue"
    ng-change="option.optionName = option.optionValue.name"
    ng-options="value.name for value in attribute.catalogue.values">
</select>
```